# Unable to project a point with Pennsylvania State Plane South

Tags: openlayers, gis, openstreetmap

I am usng the openlayers javascript API to make a map with markers in Pennsylvania State Plane South - Feet.  I followed the examples, but I cant seem to get the points to project into the OpenStreetMap projection.

I have a coordinate in the Philadelphia area that I am using for testing (2698724, 241508).  Currently, I have been unable to get OpenLayers to project the point from state plane properly.

I tried with decimal degree coordinates example and worked, so I think the coordinate system / projection is probably the issue - the rest of the code is probably correct.

I verified the coordinates of the sample point to be correct via http://www.earthpoint.us/StatePlane.aspx and selecting feet and 3702 Pennsylvania South.

I tried alerting the coordinates after the transform, and they did not change.  This leads me to think its just not projecting that point when I select a state plane coordinate system.  For this reason, the points show up in north west Africa.  I also tried converting the coordinates from feet to meters and swapping the x/y coordinates with similar results.

I tried many other projections other than ESPG:2272, such as: ESRI:102729,SR-ORG:7571,SR-ORG:7572,SR-ORG:6875,SR-ORG:6874,EPSG:2272,EPSG:3364,EPSG:3365,EPSG:3651,EPSG:3652,EPSG:32029,EPSG:32129,FIPSZONE:3702,SPC:3702,SPCS83:3702

Does anyone have any ideas on something I should try?

```
var proj = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:2272');
var point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(241508, 2698724);
point.transform(proj, map.getProjectionObject());
var feature1 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
     new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(point.lon, point.lat),
     {some:'data'},
     {externalGraphic: 'assets/1.png', graphicHeight: 21, 
     graphicWidth: 16});
vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature1);
```

Comment: OpenStreetMap uses 3857 (aka 900913), spherical mercator, which is projected and in meters. 4326 is lat/lon, which is why your points are in the sea off the coast of West Africa.

Comment: Thanks, I misspoke and updated the post accordingly.  I have already projected lat/long decimal degrees into openstreet maps projection as a test, which worked.  It does not project the state plane projections however.

Comment: Is it possible that the transformation isn't defined from these 2 are not defined?  Take a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27454/how-to-use-openlayer-transform.